Example of contractible space but not in every point.
From wikipedia the def of contractible states: "$X$ is contractible if the identity map on $X$ is [...] homotopic to some constant map [ $c:x\mapsto x_0$ ]".
All examples of contractible spaces I encountered have the identity homotopic to any constant map ($x \mapsto x_0$ for any $x_0$). 
(See examples in the wikipedia page.)
Is there a contractible space where the identity is not homotopic to all constant maps ($x \mapsto x_0$ for any $x_0$)?

What do you mean by "contractible in every point"? Contractibility is a property of a space, not a space and a point. Are you thinking of local contractibility?

If I am understanding you correctly, then the non-Hausdorff cone should be such a space.

Do you mean that a contractible space deformation retracts to every point?

Thank you all for your fast replies. I tried to explain better what I meant for "contractible to a point".

Look at the cone on the Hawaiian earring. It is contractible only to the cone point. What about the comb space?

@TedShifrin doesn't this contradict the given answer?

It depends on language. If you mean to fix the point $x_0$ throughout (“rel $x_0$), then there are examples. If you do not, then the answer applies.

The identity on a contractible space $X$ is homotopic to each constant map on $X$.
To see this, take a homotopy $H : X \times I \to X$ from the identity to a constant map $c_{x_0}$ ($c_{x_0}(x) \equiv x_0$).
Let $x_1 \in X$. Then the identity is homotopic to $c_{x_1}$ via the following homotopy:
$$H' : X \times I \to X, H'(x,t) = \begin{cases} H(x,2t) & x \le 1/2 \\ H(x_1, 2 - 2t) & t \ge 1/2 \end{cases}$$
This is a well-defined continuous map because both parts of the defnition agree for $t = 1/2$. Clearly $H'(x,0) = x$ and $H'(x,1) = x_1$ for all $x \in X$.

You opened my Eyes! Danke!
